# How to specify build variant while running integration test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, android-build-flavors, flutter-integration-test

I need to run my app with build variants config. Like this

```
flutter run --flavor dev
```

I've added some `integration_tests`, for running those I tried to use this command

```
flutter test integration_test/login_test.dart
```

How can I specify my build variants here while running tests?

Answer (score 1):

I recently migrated my integration_test to the "new version" with the next dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
   integration_test:
      sdk: flutter
   flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

It was very frustrating to have flavours enabled but not be able to run the integration test as the oficial documentation says
(by using the command:

```
flutter test test/counter_test.dart
```

The only way i found to "run" the test with the --flavor thing was by running:

```
flutter run --flavor production integration_test/app_test.dart
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `flutter test` does not support the flavor(build variant).

for this flutter, the driver is used, which allow us to mention flavor

```
flutter drive --driver=test_driver/driver.dart --target=integration_test/sample.dart --flavor dev
```